# very simple code to change attribute but not working

Tags: jquery, attr

i'm trying to change the title attribute of a div when clicking on a link but it's not working
here's the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("a#change").click(function() {
            $("#city").attr("title", "new title");          
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

and the body :

```
<a href="#" id="change">change</a>
<div id="city" title=""></div>
```

Comment: Check if You dont conflict with any other library using $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("a#change").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#city").attr("title", "new title");           
    }); 
});
```

[***Working Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/RFADu/2/)

If you want to change any property of element, you can use `.attr()` or `.prop()`. But here i used `.attr()`.

For More Examples See Documentation:

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: he wants to change the title of the div

Comment: just worked i don't know what's wrong thank you so much for helping

Answer (score 1):

try one of the following lines of code:

```
// this will change the content of the div itself
$("#city").html("new title");

// this will change the title attribute's value
$("#city").attr("title", "new title");
```

Comment: content is changing but not the title